A story about robot children looking for spare parts
I'm pretty desperate to find this story. I read a few pages from the middle of the book in 2022 and I'm pretty desperate to finish the book. I think the cover was dark blue and black with white text but I'm not sure.
These two robot children found out something was wrong with them and they went on a search for spare parts.
I vaguely remember that it was a boy and a girl, and that there were other humans, meaning humankind was not yet extinct. I also remember that at the start, they were not aware that they were robots, but I might be wrong about these details.
I also remember that when they found out where the spare parts were, they needed a human biometric, a fingerprint or something to access the factory or the cave or wherever it was.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was this a story in an anthology, or a complete novel?

It sounds sort of like the movie called Astro Boy, which is based on a manga as I understand it (I've never read it). He doesn't know he's a robot at first. He falls off the city into the junkyard below. There are humans there with him. I don't remember if there was a robot girl. There is a girl, but I think she's human.

I read a little about it and I don't think that's it. It was a novel, not a manga or a movie and I believe it had some sort of Western setting. Thanks for your help though.
